# Emacs commands hints and history

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I just reinstalled Emacs from scratch and I am missing a extension that showed hints
about the commands i am typing in the command line. It also showed a history of what i used before.

It looked something like:

```
M-x list-p {list-packages} {example-command} {example-ex1} {example-ex2}
```

I have just a basic setup with prelude right now.
I really need this extension. I learned a lot from it.

Comment: It could be M-x icomplete-mode.   In my option smex is a good option too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's maybe ido-mode (M-x ido-mode) or a bit different [emacs-helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm)

Comment: Thank you. Ido-mode seems to be pretty nice, but it is only for files and emacs-helm is also only for files. What i am looking for was a similar extensions that worked for comands and files.

Comment: Helm is not just for files. helm-M-x is for commands and helm is also for any other thing which can be completed (buffers, info, wikipedia, google, etc.). Helm has hundreds of sources for completion.

Comment: Ou Thank you tom. I'll give it a try. I just quickly looked at a tutorial and saw only find, searching, manipulation files etc. I am still looking for the other extension.

Comment: Got it. Its Helm. I didnt copy the prelude-module.el file in the main directory.